# Is there a way to Label/Annotate My Bubble Plot (Scatter plot with a z-axis) on matplotlib?

Tags: python, visualization, matplotlib

I would like to label my bubble plot, with the labels being INSIDE the bubbles. Something like this. 
 [image: Bubble plot]

Is There any way to do that?

What I've tried:

```
plt.annotate(temp.index, (temp.gre_total, temp.ugrad_gpa))
plt.show()
```

But that throws an error. I think that would only work if I looped through every value? I'm not very sure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the seaborn package, using the scatterplot marker size to generate your *bubbles*. Then you need to loop over the datapoints and add a text labet to each point in your scatterplot.

```
# Load libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Create example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
'x': [1, 1.1, 1.2, 2, 5],
'y': [5, 15, 7, 10, 2],
's': [10000,20000,30000,40000,50000],
'group': ['Stamford','Yale','Harvard','MIT','Cambridge']
})

#Create figure
plt.figure(figsize = (15,10))

# Create scatterplot. alpha controls the opacity and s controls the size.
ax = sns.scatterplot(df.x, df.y, alpha = 0.5,s = df.s)

ax.set_xlim(0,6)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 18)

#For each point, we add a text inside the bubble
for line in range(0,df.shape[0]):
     ax.text(df.x[line], df.y[line], df.group[line], horizontalalignment='center', size='medium', color='black', weight='semibold')
```

Which outputs:
[image]

Comment: I had to use iloc to put labels, just in case someone face issues with the above answer. Try replacing: `ax.text(df.x[line], df.y[line], df.group[line], horizontalalignment='center', size='medium', color='black', weight='semibold')` with: `ax.text(df.x.iloc[line], df.y.iloc[line], df.group.iloc[line], horizontalalignment='center', size='medium', color='black', weight='semibold')`

Comment: @RahulBajaj Thanks for this but is still didn't work for me.